# /usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:108: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'key1 < key2'

Tags: qt

I am trying to build QSsh on Qt4.6.3 and getting below error:

/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpoperation_p.h:92:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpUploadDir]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpoperation_p.h:167:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpDownloadDir]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpoperation_p.h:193:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QFile]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:156:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpStatFile]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:156:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::AbstractSftpOperation]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:162:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpListDir]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:168:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpMakeDir]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:174:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpRmDir]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:180:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpRm]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:187:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpRename]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:193:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpCreateLink]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:199:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpCreateFile]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:209:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpUploadFile]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:217:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpDownload]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:402:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::AbstractSftpOperationWithHandle]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h: In instantiation of 'QtSharedPointer::ExternalRefCount':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:441:   instantiated from 'QSharedPointer'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:459:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:405: warning: lowering visibility of 'QSharedPointer QtSharedPointer::copyAndSetPointer(X*, const QSharedPointer&) [with X = X, Y = Y, T = QSsh::Internal::AbstractSftpTransfer]' to match its type
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h: In function 'bool qMapLessThanKey(const Key&, const Key&) [with Key = QSharedPointer]':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:701:   instantiated from 'typename QMap::iterator QMap::erase(QMap::iterator) [with Key = QSharedPointer, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpUploadDir::Dir]'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:575:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:107: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'key1 < key2'
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qchar.h:385: note: candidates are: bool operator<(QChar, QChar)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:520: note:                 bool operator<(const QByteArray&, const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:522: note:                 bool operator<(const QByteArray&, const char*)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:524: note:                 bool operator<(const char*, const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:927: note:                 bool operator<(const char*, const QString&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:940: note:                 bool operator<(const char*, const QLatin1String&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:953: note:                 bool operator<(const QLatin1String&, const QLatin1String&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:1181: note:                 bool operator<(const QStringRef&, const QStringRef&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h: In function 'bool qMapLessThanKey(const Key&, const Key&) [with Key = QSharedPointer]':
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:646:   instantiated from 'int QMap::remove(const Key&) [with Key = QSharedPointer, T = QSsh::Internal::SftpDownloadDir::Dir]'
../../../../QSsh-master/src/libs/ssh/sftpchannel.cpp:623:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qmap.h:107: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'key1 < key2'
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qchar.h:385: note: candidates are: bool operator<(QChar, QChar)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:520: note:                 bool operator<(const QByteArray&, const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:522: note:                 bool operator<(const QByteArray&, const char*)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:524: note:                 bool operator<(const char*, const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:927: note:                 bool operator<(const char*, const QString&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:940: note:                 bool operator<(const char*, const QLatin1String&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:953: note:                 bool operator<(const QLatin1String&, const QLatin1String&)
/usr/local/qt463/qt/include/QtCore/qstring.h:1181: note:                 bool operator<(const QStringRef&, const QStringRef&)
make[3]: Leaving directory `/local_home/root/workspace/SecureUploader/qssh-build-desktop/src/libs/ssh'
make[3]: *** [.obj/debug-shared/sftpchannel.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/local_home/root/workspace/SecureUploader/qssh-build-desktop/src/libs'
make[2]: *** [sub-ssh-make_default-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local_home/root/workspace/SecureUploader/qssh-build-desktop/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-libs-make_default-ordered] Error 2
make: Leaving directory`/local_home/root/workspace/SecureUploader/qssh-build-desktop'
make: *** [sub-src-make_default-ordered] Error 2
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code %2.
Error while building project qssh (target: Desktop)

Please let me know how to resolve it

Comment: That can't be the only error message. You need to provide the complete error (and warning) log.

Comment: Please, *edit the question* to include it, don't post it as a comment!